# How do I get the file path to a Maven artifact?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

There surely must be a Maven plugin that simply prints the file path of a downloaded artifact. E.g.

```
$ mvn dependency:location -Dartifact=com.google.guava:guava:15.0
~/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/15.0/guava-15.0.jar
```

Is there such a plugin and how would I use it?

I need the path written to standard output, and not to e.g. a Maven property.

Comment: Could you provide more info on what you're trying to do? Your suggestion looks more like some sort of workaround. Maybe there's a better way to solve the real issue.

Comment: @RobertScholte I need to download a JAR via Maven and execute it (The manifest contains a main class and the JAR has shaded dependencies).

Comment: so do you want to bundle both the JARs together, i.e your own JAR which is dependent on the downloaded JAR? right?

Comment: @dreamer, no I simply want to execute a JAR that contains a tool used by a batch script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dependency:copy](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html), which will download and save the artifact in a specified outputDirectory (default: target/dependency).
This way you don't have to worry about local or remote repositories, Maven will solve that for you.

Comment: I have seen this goal before, but discarded it because this command will be run with different artifacts and in different directories. It is unfortunate that it will have to maintain a separate copy of the artifacts it relies on. But it works, so I will accept this solution.